# CSS background is less than div hight

Tags: html, css, css-float, word-wrap

Help me please, I can't understand result of my simply code:

```
<div id="wrapper-top">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="logo">logo</div>
        <div id="menu">menu</div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="block-1-1">text</div>
            <div class="block-3-1">text</div>
            <div class="block-3-2">text</div>
            <div class="block-3-3">text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css file:

```
#wrapper-top
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
}
.wrapper
{
    margin: 0 150px 0 150px;
}
#logo
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
#menu
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: navajowhite;
}
#content
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
.block-1-1
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: pink;
}
.block-3-1
{
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: violet;
}
.block-3-2
{
    float:left;
    width:34%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
.block-3-3
{
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

Why divs **.block-3-1**, **.block-3-2** and **.block-3-3** seem to be outside of div **.wrapper**. 
[image]

I don't expected that because I want this blocks inside **.wrapper**.

http://jsfiddle.net/4yvLv853/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to contain the floated items in the `#content` div

One method (there are others as detailed [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best/1633170#1633170)) is to use `overflow:hidden`

```
#content
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/4yvLv853/3/)

Answer (score 0):

use `clearfix`

```css
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}



#wrapper-top
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    border: solid blue 1px;
}
.wrapper
{
    margin: 0 150px 0 150px;
    border: solid brown 1px;
}


#logo
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
#menu
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: navajowhite;
}
#content
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
.block-1-1
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: pink;
}
.block-3-1
{
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: violet;
}
.block-3-2
{
    float:left;
    width:34%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
.block-3-3
{
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-top">
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div id="logo">logo</div>
        <div id="menu">menu</div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="block-1-1">block-1-1</div>
            <div class="block-3-1">block-3-1</div>
            <div class="block-3-2">block-3-2</div>
            <div class="block-3-3">block-3-3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<div id="wrapper-top">
    <div class="wrapper" style="height: 400px"> //You can add this in CSS if you want.
        <div id="logo">logo</div>
        <div id="menu">menu</div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="block-1-1">text</div>
            <div class="block-3-1">text</div>
            <div class="block-3-2">text</div>
            <div class="block-3-3">text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think the wrapper height is too small.

Alternatively, if you want the .wrapper div to stay the height it is, try changing the `#content` to

```
#content {
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;  //this gets rid of the pesky bottom scrollbar
}
```